# Touch event does not do any action on the Unity c # smartphone

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, 3d

I have this code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;
using UnityEngine.Audio;
using UnityEngine.EventSystems;

public class start : MonoBehaviour, IPointerDownHandler, IPointerUpHandler
{
    public GameObject musica;
    public bool pulsado;
    // Use this for initialization
    void Start()
    {

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {

    }
    public void OnPointerDown(PointerEventData eventData)
    {
        pulsado = true;
        audio();
        SceneManager.LoadScene("pajaro");
    }
    public void OnPointerUp(PointerEventData eventData)
    {
        pulsado = false;
    }
    void audio()
    {
        musica.SetActive(true);
    }
}
```

When I export it to Android, touch does not work, but if it works in unity

Comment: I think you might want to edit that before you get an avalanche of downvotes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using `OnPointerDown`, this is *specific* to the mouse, this event does not fire for Touch input (touch input does not have a concept of "up" and "down").

In order to have touch input, you have to use `Input.touches` during the `Update()` loop.